# Continuous questions

Tags: python

**Code:**

```
import json
import random

questions = json.load(open("questions.json"))

question = random.choice(questions.keys())

answers = questions[question]['answers']
correct_answer = questions[question]['correct_answer']

print question
for n, answer in enumerate(answers):
    print "%d) %s" % (n + 1, answer)

resp = raw_input('answer: ')
if resp == str(correct_answer):
    print "correct!"
else:   
    print "sorry, the correct answer was %s" % correct_answer
```

**question.json:**

```
{
  "What are your plans for today?": {
    "answers": ["nothing", "something", "do not know"],
    "correct_answer": 2
  },
  "how are you?": {
    "answers": ["well", "badly", "do not know"],
    "correct_answer": 1
  }
}
```

I would like to know how can I make this program continuing asking questions, even if the answer is right or wrong, like doing continuing questions, without stoping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to ask all questions in a random order, you can use `random.shuffle` and ask them all with a `for` loop.

```
import json
import random

# use items to get a list    
questions = json.load(open("questions.json")).items()
# ... that you can shuffle.
random.shuffle(questions)
# note, we used items() earlier, so we get a tuple.
# and we can ask all questions in random order.
for question, data in questions:
   answers = data['answers']
   correct_answer = data['correct_answer']
   print question
   for n, answer in enumerate(answers):
       print "%d) %s" % (n + 1, answer)
   resp = raw_input('answer: ')
   if resp == str(correct_answer):
       print "correct!"
   else:   
       print "sorry, the correct answer was %s" % correct_answer
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted. tanksss